How to Mock EntityEntry in EF Core?
I am trying to write a unit test for a method that handles exceptions and reloads an entity in Entity Framework Core. The method contains the following code:
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        await context.Entry(myEntityInstance).ReloadAsync();
    }
    catch { return null; };

I have successfully mocked SaveChangesAsync to throw the desired exception. However, I am encountering issues when attempting to mock the Entry method:
contextMock.Setup(c => c.Entry(It.IsAny<MyEntity>()).ReloadAsync(default))

This results in an ArgumentException:

Can not instantiate proxy of class: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry ...
Could not find a parameterless constructor. (Parameter 'constructorArguments') ---> System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'Castle.Proxies.EntityEntry`1Proxy' not found.

The problem is that EntityEntry<TEntity> is not mock-friendly because it has only one constructor:
[EntityFrameworkInternal]
public EntityEntry(InternalEntityEntry internalEntry)

InternalEntityEntry is an internal EF Core class that depends on instances of other internal classes. There is a GitHub issue Trouble Mocking EntityEntry discussing this problem, but it seems that the EF team is not planning to make any changes.
How can I mock EntityEntry in EF Core to test this method effectively?

It's strongly recommended to test such things in integration tests. Intricate mocking easily introduces bugs or oversights that change the actual behavior.

Because it is concurrency problem it is difficult to simulate and maybe never happen in reality so I wanted to see it running at least in some test. On the other hand EntityEntry mocking is more general and can be sometimes useful.

After thoroughly examining the EF Core source code, I created the following method to mock EntityEntry. This method relies heavily on internal APIs, but it avoids reflection. If a future breaking change occurs, it can be easily identified and the test can be corrected.
    /// <summary>
    /// Mocks an <see cref="EntityEntry"/>  for a given entity in the specified DbContext.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TContext">The type of the DbContext.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The type of the entity.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="dbContextMock">The mock of the DbContext.</param>
    /// <param name="entity">The entity to mock the entry for.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Mock"> of the <see cref="EntityEntry"/> for the specified entity.</returns>
    /// <remarks>The method heavilly depends on "Internal EF Core API" and so can fail after EF upgrade. Use with extreme care.</remarks>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Usage", "EF1001:Internal EF Core API usage.", Justification = "<Pending>")]
    public static Mock<EntityEntry<TEntity>> MockEntityEntry<TContext, TEntity>(Mock<TContext> dbContextMock, TEntity entity)
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
    {
        var stateManagerMock = new Mock<IStateManager>();
        stateManagerMock
            .Setup(x => x.CreateEntityFinder(It.IsAny<IEntityType>()))
            .Returns(new Mock<IEntityFinder>().Object);
        stateManagerMock
            .Setup(x => x.ValueGenerationManager)
            .Returns(new Mock<IValueGenerationManager>().Object);
        stateManagerMock
            .Setup(x => x.InternalEntityEntryNotifier)
            .Returns(new Mock<IInternalEntityEntryNotifier>().Object);

        var entityTypeMock = new Mock<IRuntimeEntityType>();
        var keyMock = new Mock<IKey>();
        keyMock
            .Setup(x => x.Properties)
            .Returns([]);
        entityTypeMock
            .Setup(x => x.FindPrimaryKey())
            .Returns(keyMock.Object);
        entityTypeMock
            .Setup(e => e.EmptyShadowValuesFactory)
            .Returns(() => new Mock<ISnapshot>().Object);

        var internalEntityEntry = new InternalEntityEntry(stateManagerMock.Object, entityTypeMock.Object, entity);

        var entityEntryMock = new Mock<EntityEntry<TEntity>>(internalEntityEntry);
        dbContextMock
            .Setup(c => c.Entry(It.IsAny<TEntity>()))
            .Returns(() => entityEntryMock.Object);

        return entityEntryMock;
    }

Using the result of this method, you can easily create the desired mock for ReloadAsync:
 entityEntryMock.Setup(e => e.ReloadAsync(default)).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

